# JOIN category and subcategory in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following tables -

categories

```
+-----------+-------------+
|  column   |    type     |
+-----------+-------------+
| id        | int(11)     |
| ctid      | int(11)     |
| name      | varchar(40) |
| ToAmount  | int(11)     |
| is_active | tinyint(1)  |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Subcategories

```
+-----------+-------------+
|  column   |    type     |
+-----------+-------------+
| id        | int(11)     |
| sid       | varchar(40) |
| name      | varchar(50) |
| Amount    | int(11)     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I Need to join these two tables,the resulting table should contain the categories and subcategories in one field

Example table one have categories and also other items also

Categories

```
+----+------------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name      | ctid         |ToAmount    |
+----+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | apple      |              | 100        |
|  2 | nonveg     |     1        | 350        |
|  3 | orange     |              | 150        |
|  4 | furniture  |     2        | 200        |
+----+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Subcategories

```
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  |   sid        |Amount      |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | chair  |     2        | 100        |
|  2 | meat   |     1        | 200        |
|  3 | chicken|     1        | 150        |
|  4 | stool  |     2        | 100        |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

I need to join these two tables and make in one field
**expected result**

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id |  name  |   Amount     |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | apple  |   100        |
|  2 | meat   |   200        |
|  3 | chicken|   150        |
|  4 | orange |   150        |
|  5 | stool  |   100        |         
|  6 | chair  |   100        |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

**Result i am getting**

```
SELECT `categories`.`id`,
           `categories`.`ToAmount`AS Ccost,
           `ategories`.`name ` AS Sname,
           `subcategories`.`name` As Noname,
           `subcategories`.`Amount` As Scost
    FROM (`categories`)
    LEFT JOIN `subcategories` 
        ON `categories`.`ctid` = `subcategories`.`sid`

+----+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| id |  Cname   | Ccost        |   Sname     | Scost    |
+----+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|  1 | apple    | 100          |             |          |
|  2 | nonveg   | 350          | meat        | 200      |
|  3 | nonveg   | 350          | chicken     | 150      |
|  4 | furnitere| 200          | stool       | 100      |
|  5 | furnitere| 200          | chair       | 100      |
|  6 | orange   | 150          |             |          |
+----+----------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

in this result the furniture and nonveg cateogries is listing,i dont want this cateogries to list in the resulting table

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: @Richu please, edit the expected result table as you don't need furniture there.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you expected result (a bit artificial solution according to vague conditions in the question):

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS id,
       name,
       Amount
FROM (SELECT
        Sub.`name` AS name,
        Sub.`Amount` AS Amount
      FROM `subcategories` as Sub
      UNION
      SELECT
        Cat.`name` AS name,
        Cat.`ToAmount` AS Amount
      FROM `categories` as Cat
      WHERE Cat.`ctid` IS NULL) AS Commontable
```

Note, that your Categories also contains Subcategories (for example apple and orange), so the tables have wrong structure initially, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT c.`id`,
       COALESCE(sc.Amount, c.ToAmount) as cost,
       COALESCE(sc.name, c.name) as Name
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN
     subcategories sc
     ON c.ctid = sc.sid;
```

The idea is to do a `LEFT JOIN`.  If the value exists in `subcategories`, then use it.  Otherwise, use the value in `categories`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.id ,
  case when s.name is null then c.name else s.name  end as name ,
  case when s.amount is null then c.ToAmount else s.amount  end as amount
   from Categories  c
left  join  Subcategories s on s.sid=c.ctid
```

Comment: Tested and working fine (if you wish you change ID's number )